# Using off to unbind query event

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I tried to create a simple solution for ordering problem in async calls on a project I'm working on.

The best solution I found was this:
I attach an event that check if the pre-requirements are done, if so I remove the event listener and perform the function.

Each function calls the event once its done and that way everyone will be waiting until the can run.

This is the code:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('bmadone',function() {
        if(beepmeapp.done_arr['fb-init']){
            $(document).off('bmadone','#bma-root',this);
            getBMAUserRoutes();
        }
    });
});
```

The function (for the test) is doing this:

```
function getBMAUserRoutes(){
    $.ajax({
        url     : '/bma/users/fb',
        type    : 'GET',
        data    : {
            access_token: 'abc'
        },
        success : function( data ) {
            console.log('getBMAUser: success');
            beepmeapp.done_arr['user-init'] = true;
            $('#bma-root').trigger('bmadone');
        },
        error   : function( xhr, err ) {
            console.log('getBMAUser: error');
        }
    });    
}
```

It works great but the problem I have is that it gets into a loop that never ends.
Don't know why but it looks like:

```
$(document).off('bmadone','#bma-root',this);
```

Doesn't remove the listener...

I'm a true newbie in JS / Jquery and all of this client side development so I guess I'm probably missing something basic.

Comment: "this" might not be what you think it is. ;)

Comment: Instead of  `$(document).off('bmadone','#bma-root',this);` try  `$(document).off('bmadone');` suppose that will work

Comment: the problem is that $(document).off('bmadone'); will remove all the handlers and I need to remove only one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the same (sub)set of parameters to `.off` that you passed to `.on`. I.e. in your case it would be `$(document).off('bmadone')`.

You never passed `'#bma-root'` to `.on` and `this` does *not* refer to the event handler (the function you pass to `.on`), so by passing those you won't remove the correct event handler.

---

If you need to remove only that specific handler, you can use a named function instead:

```
function handler() {
    if(beepmeapp.done_arr['fb-init']){
        $(document).off('bmadone', handler);
        getBMAUserRoutes();
    }
}

$(document).on('bmadone', handler);

// or as a named function expression

$(document).on('bmadone', function handler() {
    if(beepmeapp.done_arr['fb-init']){
        $(document).off('bmadone', handler);
        getBMAUserRoutes();
    }
});
```

or use [namespaced events](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events).

Comment: Isn't the use of 'this' in the off is basically the function object?

Comment: No, it refers to `document`. `this` never refers to the function unless you *explicitly* set it so.

Comment: How do I set it to do so? I don't want to create a function just for the sake of calling it on the off call - there must be a way to point to the current anonymous function.

Comment: You are creating a function either way. Anonymous functions are functions too ;). If you don't care about problems in older IE browsers, you can use a named function expression... will update my answer. Or you could use namespaced events, as I already said.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion and it looks great, I still get multiple calls (maybe its because some of the function are getting called before they have the ability to remove themselves (the handlers) from the event. - Maybe a better approach will be to have one handler that handle all the function that way I can make sure every function runs one once.